# Installing autobahn with node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, autobahn

I am new to nodejs and looking to run some simple code on Ubuntu 16.04.

I have installed nodejs and npm

```
root@coding:~# node -v
v6.3.0
root@coding:~# npm -v
3.10.3
```

I am now looking to install autobahn as per:
http://autobahn.ws/js/gettingstarted.html

Unfortunately I get:

```
root@coding:~# npm install autobahn

> bufferutil@1.2.1 install /root/node_modules/bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
make: Entering directory '/root/node_modules/bufferutil/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node
  COPY Release/bufferutil.node
make: Leaving directory '/root/node_modules/bufferutil/build'

> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install /root/node_modules/utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
make: Entering directory '/root/node_modules/utf-8-validate/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node
  COPY Release/validation.node
make: Leaving directory '/root/node_modules/utf-8-validate/build'
/root
└─┬ autobahn@0.10.1 
  ├─┬ bufferutil@1.2.1 
  │ ├── bindings@1.2.1 
  │ └── nan@2.4.0 
  ├── crypto-js@3.1.6 
  ├─┬ msgpack-lite@0.1.20 
  │ ├── event-lite@0.1.1 
  │ ├── ieee754@1.1.6 
  │ ├── int64-buffer@0.1.9 
  │ └── isarray@1.0.0 
  ├── utf-8-validate@1.2.1 
  ├── when@3.7.7 
  └─┬ ws@1.1.1 
    ├── options@0.0.6 
    └── ultron@1.0.2 

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/package.json'
npm WARN root No description
npm WARN root No repository field.
npm WARN root No README data
npm WARN root No license field.
```

Comment: Warnings aren't errors. Looks like out worked to me.

Comment: Thanks Robert, yes it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WARNING-1:**

```
gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
```

*REASON:* One of the dependencies of either your npm or autobahn is using a deprecated library or function, which is `NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR` in this case. If your npm is already upto date, don't worry the guys at `autobahn` will fix it. Raise an issue with them if you feel so.

**WARNING-2:**

```
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/package.json'
npm WARN root No description
npm WARN root No repository field.
npm WARN root No README data
npm WARN root No license field.
```

*REASON:* You don't have a package.json. Simply run `npm init` and follow the instructions and it'll create one for you.

**CONCLUSION:**

Either way both are warning. Check your `node_modules\` folder and to most probability everything should be installed becase there was no errors listed.